DNN edit mode not working after 2sxc upgrade
When I upgrade 2sxc to 17.9 or 18.6.1 on a certain DNN installation I get an error:
[ERROR] DotNetNuke.Common.Internal.EventHandlersContainer`1[[DotNetNuke.Entities.Profile.IProfileEventHandlers, DotNetNuke, Version=9.11.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] - De type-initialisatiefunctie voor DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.ExtensionPointManager heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt.
System.TypeInitializationException: De type-initialisatiefunctie voor DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.ExtensionPointManager heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt. ---> System.TypeLoadException: Kan type ToSic.Eav.Documentation.PublicApi niet laden vanuit assembly ToSic.Eav.Core, Version=17.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
   bij System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   bij System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   bij System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   bij System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   bij System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsCustomAttributeDefined(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Int32 attributeCtorToken, Boolean mustBeInheritable)
   bij System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.IsDefined(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   bij System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedPartCreationInfo.IsPartDiscoverable()
   bij System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModel.AttributedModelDiscovery.CreatePartDefinitionIfDiscoverable(Type type, ICompositionElement origin)
   bij System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.TypeCatalog.get_PartsInternal()
   bij System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.TypeCatalog.GetEnumerator()
   bij System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   bij System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   bij DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.SafeDirectoryCatalog..ctor(String directory)
   bij DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.ExtensionPointManager.InitializeMefCompositionContainer()
   bij DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.ExtensionPointManager..cctor()
   --- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad ---
   bij DotNetNuke.ExtensionPoints.ExtensionPointManager.ComposeParts(Object[] attributeParts)
   bij DotNetNuke.Common.Internal.EventHandlersContainer`1..ctor()

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Just for reference, I had some contact with 2sxc and they said it was an old dll which was still in the bin folder. So it looks like this was not deleted after and upgrade. In my case I had to delete the ToSic.EAV.Tokens.dll file from the bin folder and then everything worked again.
